# Checking Array Values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm developing a page that is a quiz for Valentine's Day.

There are 4 quiz and among these 4 you have some options. After selecting these 4 options, a button appears for the user to see the result of the destination. All that calm, I would like to know if there is a way to improve or optimize a part of the code.

This part I'm talking about is checking the array, for example. If it is 'night, heat, Brazil and adventure', the result will be 'Rio de Janeiro'. There are several destinations and I did everything for if and it was very big. Is there another way that would be better?

```js
let valueInfos;

if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("calor") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("brasil") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("aventura") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["Chapada diamantina", "O Parque Nacional da Chapada Diamantina é uma região de serras, vales, rios, cachoeiras, grutas e de muitas aventuras para você curtir muito durante o dia.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/chapada-diamantina"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("calor") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("brasil") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("romantica") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["GRAMADO", "Para os românticos de plantão, preparem-se para o encanto da beleza única de Gramado.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/gramado"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("calor") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("brasil") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("tranquila") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["FERNANDO DE NORONHA", "Fernando de Noronha é perfeita para você curtir dias de sol em algumas das praias mais especiais de todo o país, sem contar a agitada vida marinha.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/fernando-de-noronha"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("calor") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("exterior") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("aventura") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["RESERVA MASAI MARA", "Já pensou em visitar a África? A reserva Masai Mara fica no Quênica e é um destino perfeito para os aventureiros que buscam explorar a vida selvagem da savana africana.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/reserva-masai-mara-no-quenia"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("calor") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("exterior") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("romantica") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["CANCÚN", "Se para você o melhor jeito de curtir o dia com é dentro de um mar com águas cristalinas, resorts e vida noturna seu destino tem que ser Cancún.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/cancun"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("calor") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("exterior") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("Tranquila") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["VENEZA", "Quem nunca sonhou com um passeio de gôndola em Veneza? A beleza da cidade italiana é incomparável para aqueles que preferem um destino tranquilo e com uma culinária esplêndida.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/veneza"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("frio") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("brasil") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("aventura") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["CANELA", "Explore o Lago Negro, a flora e a arquitetura importada da Alemanha e Itália nesse destino único.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/gramado-e-canela"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("frio") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("brasil") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("romantica") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["GRAMADO", "Se sua viagem dos sonhos envolve temperaturas baixas e passeios ao ar livre, prepare-se para se encantar pela beleza única de Gramado.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/gramado"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("frio") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("brasil") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("tranquila") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["PORTO ALEGRE", "Gosta de passear ao ar livre, ver o pôr do sol e ainda pegar um barzinho ou restaurante depois? A capital gaúcha é o seu destino.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/porto-alegre"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("frio") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("exterior") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("aventura") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["CHILE", "O Chile é conhecido não só pela sua cordilheira, mas por ter o céu mais bonito do mundo. Prepare-se para assistir um show de estrelas no deserto do Atacama.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/santiago"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("frio") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("exterior") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("romantico") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["PARIS", "Pensou em romance, pensou em Paris. A capital francesa é há séculos considerada uma das cidades mais elegantes do mundo inteiro, capaz de conquistar qualquer coração.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/paris"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("dia") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("frio") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("exterior") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("tranquila") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["BARILOCHE", "Frio, neve e chocolate. Não tem passeio mais gostoso que curtir um clima diferente como este argentino.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/bariloche"];
} else if (dataQuiz.indexOf("noite") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("calor") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("brasil") > -1 && dataQuiz.indexOf("aventura") > -1) {
  valueInfos = ["RIO DE JANEIRO", "Praia, mar, uma orla maravilhosa e uma vida noturna incrível vão fazer você se apaixonar por este destino.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/rio-de-janeiro"];
}

return valueInfos;
```

Comment: Unable to understand the usecase of this code, add more information such as what's the significance of `dataQuiz` and `valueInfos` variables. Also include the **'night, heat, Brazil and adventure'** example in the code snippet itself for better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would create a constant for each city and each kind of filter/attributes you can have like `calor`, `frio`, `dia`, `night`...

```js
const SHIFTS = {
  DAY: 'dia',
  NIGHT: 'noite',
}

const TEMPERATURES = {
  HOT: 'calor',
  COLD: 'frio',
}

const LOCATIONS = {
  BRAZIL: 'brasil',
  ABROAD: 'exterior',
}

const GENRES = {
  ADVENTURE: 'aventura',
  ROMANTIC: 'romantica',
  QUIET: 'tranquila',
}
```

Then I would create each city in a constant so, keep easy to know how many cities do you have and what are the attributes and add them in a `CITIES` constant:

```js
const CHAPADA_DIAMANTINA = {
  filters: {
    shift: SHIFTS.DAY,
    temperature: TEMPERATURES.HOT,
    location: LOCATIONS.BRAZIL,
    genre: GENRES.ADVENTURE,
  },
  content: {
    title: "Chapada diamantina", 
    body: "O Parque Nacional da Chapada Diamantina é uma região de serras, vales, rios, cachoeiras, grutas e de muitas aventuras para você curtir muito durante o dia.", 
    link: "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/chapada-diamantina",
  },
}

const GRAMADO = {
  filters: {
    shift: SHIFTS.DAY,
    temperature: TEMPERATURES.HOT,
    location: LOCATIONS.BRAZIL,
    genre: GENRES.ADVENTURE,
  },
  content: {
    title: "GRAMADO", 
    body: "Para os românticos de plantão, preparem-se para o encanto da beleza única de Gramado.", 
    link: "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/gramado"
  },
}

...

const CITIES = [CHAPADA_DIAMANTINA, GRAMADO, ...]
```

Also, I don't know how you are creating the `dataQuiz` array but I would prefer to create an object instead. Just link `filters` in each city

```js
{
  shift: 'dia|noite',                   // SHIFTS
  temperature: 'calor|frio',            // TEMPERATURES
  location: 'brasil|exterior',          // LOCATIONS
  genre: 'aventura|romantica|tranquila' // GENRES
}
```

So, now you can keep your logic short

```js
const quizMatchesWithCity = (quiz, city) => {
  const { filters } = city
  
  // you can use isEqual from lodash or ramda
  return isEqual(quiz, filter)
  
  // or with vanilla JS
  const props = Object.keys(quiz) // ['shift', 'temperature', 'location', 'genre']
  return props.every(prop => {
    const quizValue = quiz[prop]
    const cityFilterValue = city[prop]

    return quizValue === cityFilterValue
  }) 
}

// I would change `dataQuiz` to something like
// {
//   shift: 'dia|noite', 
//   temperature: 'calor|frio',
//   location: 'brasil|exterior',
//   genre: 'aventura|romantica|tranquila'
// }
const getContent = (dataQuiz) => {
  const city = CITIES.find(city => quizMatchesWithCity(dataQuiz, city))

  if (city) {
    const { content } = city
    const { 
      title,
      body,
      link,
    } = content

    return [title, body, link]
  }

  return ['NOT FOUND', '', '']
}
```

That's it.
Did you like it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of different approaches to simplifying the code but they all lead you to the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). Therefore, it is smart to put all of the `valueInfos` into an array of objects that you can reference via the key, which is an array of all the options. The data structure would look like this:

```
let valueInfos = [
    {
        options: ['dia', 'calor', 'brasil', 'aventura'],
        infos: ["Chapada diamantina", "O Parque Nacional da Chapada Diamantina é uma região de serras, vales, rios, cachoeiras, grutas e de muitas aventuras para você curtir muito durante o dia.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/chapada-diamantina"]
    },
    {
        options: ['dia', 'calor', 'brasil', 'romantica'],
        infos: ["GRAMADO", "Para os românticos de plantão, preparem-se para o encanto da beleza única de Gramado.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/gramado"];
    },
    // add in all your other option-info pairs
]
```

Next, you want to find that pair, which includes all the options that are also in `dataQuiz`. This can be done in just one final line:

```
return valueInfos.find(vi => vi.options.every(option => dataQuiz.includes(option)))
```

What's happening here is that we look through every option-infos pair `vi` in the `valueInfos` array until we *find* a match (a true statement). We get a true statement when *every* option of a pair is also *included* in your `dataQuiz` array. Notice how I highlighted the keywords that match the JS functions to make it a little easier to understand.

Additionally, I recommend you turn the infos arrays into objects with keys called something like 'title', 'description' and 'link'.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what element is in what position opposed to just an unknown 'dataQuiz'.

for example are you able to get the info like this:

```
dataQuiz[0]  (where this would be 'dia' or 'noite')
dataQuiz[1]  (this would be 'calor' or 'frio')
dataQuiz[2]  (... and so on)
...
```

if you know the order, then I would use a map:

```
var _dataMap = {
    dia: {
        calor:{
            brasil: {
                aventura: ["Chapada diamantina", "O Parque Nacional da Chapada Diamantina é uma região de serras, vales, rios, cachoeiras, grutas e de muitas aventuras para você curtir muito durante o dia.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/chapada-diamantina"],
                romantica: ["GRAMADO", "Para os românticos de plantão, preparem-se para o encanto da beleza única de Gramado.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/gramado"],
                tranquila: ["FERNANDO DE NORONHA", "Fernando de Noronha é perfeita para você curtir dias de sol em algumas das praias mais especiais de todo o país, sem contar a agitada vida marinha.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/fernando-de-noronha"]
            },
            exterior: {
                aventura: ["RESERVA MASAI MARA", "Já pensou em visitar a África? A reserva Masai Mara fica no Quênica e é um destino perfeito para os aventureiros que buscam explorar a vida selvagem da savana africana.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/reserva-masai-mara-no-quenia"],
                romantica: ["CANCÚN", "Se para você o melhor jeito de curtir o dia com é dentro de um mar com águas cristalinas, resorts e vida noturna seu destino tem que ser Cancún.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/cancun"],
                Tranquila: ["VENEZA", "Quem nunca sonhou com um passeio de gôndola em Veneza? A beleza da cidade italiana é incomparável para aqueles que preferem um destino tranquilo e com uma culinária esplêndida.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/veneza"]
            }
        },
        frio: {
            brasil: {
                aventura: ["CANELA", "Explore o Lago Negro, a flora e a arquitetura importada da Alemanha e Itália nesse destino único.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/gramado-e-canela"],
                romantica: ["GRAMADO", "Se sua viagem dos sonhos envolve temperaturas baixas e passeios ao ar livre, prepare-se para se encantar pela beleza única de Gramado.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/gramado"],
                tranquila: ["PORTO ALEGRE", "Gosta de passear ao ar livre, ver o pôr do sol e ainda pegar um barzinho ou restaurante depois? A capital gaúcha é o seu destino.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/porto-alegre"]
            },
            exterior: {
                aventura: ["CHILE", "O Chile é conhecido não só pela sua cordilheira, mas por ter o céu mais bonito do mundo. Prepare-se para assistir um show de estrelas no deserto do Atacama.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/santiago"],
                romantica: ["PARIS", "Pensou em romance, pensou em Paris. A capital francesa é há séculos considerada uma das cidades mais elegantes do mundo inteiro, capaz de conquistar qualquer coração.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/paris"],
                tranquila: ["BARILOCHE", "Frio, neve e chocolate. Não tem passeio mais gostoso que curtir um clima diferente como este argentino.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/bariloche"]
            }
        }
    },
    noite:{
        calor:{
            brasil: {
                aventura: ["RIO DE JANEIRO", "Praia, mar, uma orla maravilhosa e uma vida noturna incrível vão fazer você se apaixonar por este destino.", "https://www.smiles.com.br/dicas-smiles/destinos/rio-de-janeiro"]
            }
        }
    }
};

function getInfo(){
    try{return _dataMap[dataQuiz[0]][dataQuiz[1]][dataQuiz[2]][dataQuiz[3]]}catch(e){return false;}
    
}
```